# Python use OR operator

Tags: python

I am new in Python and I try to sense the difference between two expression.

Is that:

```
a=1
if a==0 or 1:
  print (a)
```

is same as:

```
a=1
if a==0 or a==1:
  print(a)
```

Comment: `bool(1)` is `True`.. always.. always.. always.

Comment: Did you even try to execute this code?

Comment: Downvoters, why? He is asking a completely fine question.

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: This is only a duplicate if you happen to know to phrase it in a completely different way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `==` instead of `=`. `=` is an assignment operator whereas `==` checks if the two are equal. Also, the first bit of code is not correct. You have to rewrite the entire condition.